# Reactjs fetch data from API and google SEO problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo

My website create with ReactJS and all data get from API

This is fetch code:

```
fetch('myApiUrl').then(response => response.json()).then(jsonData => {
    this.setState({
        title: jsonData.title
    })
})
```

And this is render code:

```
render() {
    return (<h1>{this.state.title}</h1>)
}
```

So, if user open the website, title show to user but if google crawl the website, title not showing to google.

How can I fix this problem and get data from api and google can read it?

Comment: Maybe you should look into NextJs. It uses SSR so that Google can crawl the content on the website.

Comment: @Reinier68 thank you. so reactjs can not handle it?

Comment: Well, I am not an expert, but I do know that by default, SPA's (so apps built with Vue/React/Angular etc) are hard for Google to index the content on the website properly. That's one of the reasons why NuxtJs (Vuejs but with SSR ability) and NextJs (React with SSR ability) were created. So there are probably npm packages that can help you, but if indexing the content is important to your app, it might be worth to look into frameworks that do the heavy lifting for you.